# How can I summarize the changes users have made in git?

Tags: git

Is there one command that I can use to summarize all the changes (i.e., number of commits, number of insertions and deletions) users have made in a repo? I have used `git shortlog --no-merges -sn` to see the number of commits but I'd like to include the number of insertions and deletions as well. I do not want to specify a specific author to be summarized.

UPDATE: The reason I don't want to specify authors is that I want to be able to run a script on multiple repos without any intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Your need is what like these
Number of commits https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-count

Number of insertions and deletions (blame) https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-guilt

or

```
git log --shortstat | \
awk '/^ [0-9]/ { f += $1; i += $4; d += $6 } \
END { printf("%d files changed, %d insertions(+), %d deletions(-)", f, i, d) }'
```

For example, at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/

[image]